# Allow any field in Prisma

Tags: mongodb, prisma

How do I allow any field to be added in Prisma? What I mean by this is something like `[key: String]: String` in TypeScript. I use mongoDB as a database.

Comment: Prisma cannot have unspecified/arbitrary fields at the model level at the moment.

It would be great if you could create a [new feature request](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&template=feature_request.md&title=) for this, along with your use-case so we can track interest in this feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prisma doesn't allow passing objects to query methods (e.g. CRUD Methods) with additional fields. You would need to filter out the object with fields which are recognized by Prisma before passing it to query methods.

Here's the official Feature Request: [Don't throw error when passing object with additional fields](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/14481) which discusses allowing arbitrary fields to prisma.